# Simple field to display static data

Tags: entities, social-network

I am trying to do module with different share buttons in form of field to content type. It has no settings, I just need to enable it in admin panel and the button should appear on node. But I cannot get to work simple sample of code like this:

```
function fblike_field_info() {
    return array(
        'fblike' => array(
            'label' => t('Facebook Like'),
            'description' => t('This field displays Facebook Like button.'),
            'settings' => array(),
            'instance_settings' => array(),
            'default_widget' => 'fblike_default_widget',
            'default_formatter' => 'fblike_default_formatter',
        ),
    );
}

function fblike_field_widget_info() {
    return array(
        'fblike_default_widget' => array(
            'label' => 'Like Box',
            'field types' => array('fblike'),
        ),
    );
}

function fblike_field_formatter_info() {
    return array(
        'fblike_default_formatter' => array(
            'label' => t('Like Box (default)'),
            'field types' => array('fblike'),
        ),
    );
}

function fblike_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
    $link = '<div class="fb-like" data-href="HTTP://ENTER.YOUR.URL.HERE" data-width="80" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>';

    $element = array();
    $element[0] = array('#markup' => $link);

    return $element;
}
```

The result of this code is:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-lubi-to field-type-fblike field-label-above">
    <div class="field-label">Like:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field-items"></div>
</div>
```

I already run out of ideas. I have created many modules with fields before, but none was that simple... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got this. As far as my field has nothing in $items, in order to print something I had to use this snippet:

```
function fblike_field_prepare_view($entity_type, $entities, $field, $instances, $langcode, &$items) {
    foreach ($entities as $id => $entity) {
        if (empty($items[$id])) {
            $items[$id][0] = 'something';
        }
    }
}
```